# How colloquial is "I won't forgive me"?

Tags: slang

I heard it in an Adele song (He won't go), and I know she's using not-exactly-proper english sometimes (like "she ain't gon' be"), but I can't tell if I've just never heard it or if it's not correct.

Is it OK to say in an informal conversation?

Here is the verse from the song (full lyrics [here](http://genius.com/Adele-he-wont-go-lyrics)):

> So petrified, I'm so scared to step into this ride,
>   What if I lose my heart and fail the climb
>   **I won't forgive me** if I gave up trying
>   I heard his voice today
>   I didn't know a single word he said
>   Not one resemblance to the man I met
>   Just a vague and broken boy instead

Comment: It isn't colloquial at all, at least, not in BrE. Perhaps what is meant is "I cannot forgive myself"?

Comment: Careful with song lyrics. Writers bend the rules of English grammar all the time for the sake of fitting the words inside of the rhythm, meter, and rhyming scheme of the song. That seems to be the case here.

Comment: +! @J.R. If you like _I won't forgive me,_ wait til you get to _Now I'm resemblance to the man I met!_

Comment: @p-e-dant Actually these aren't the correct lyrics... I went to a reliable lyrics site and edited the post. There was another mistake : step into this **ride** (instead of right)

Comment: @Goat Well, that makes more sense. In the line you cite, the writer uses _won't_ instead of _wouldn't_ because the two syllables of the latter word don't "scan": they violate the meter of the verse. She would have been better off putting "give" in the present tense, but these songwriters never have the good sense to ask for _my_ advice!

Comment: @P.E.Dant is it correct to say "I wouldn't forgive me" ? I'd still use *myself* here. Basically my question is, I know it's not proper, but is it acceptable to use with friend, in a very informal context ? If songwriters use it it must not hurt the ear that much right ?

Comment: You're right. Correct grammar calls for the _reflexive pronoun_ here: _I wouldn't/won't forgive **myself.**_ But even informally, no, we would not hear _I won't forgive me_ in conversation. A listener would be likely to infer that the speaker is not a native English speaker. This was written only to force the thought into the meter of the verse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to say this is *I won't forgive myself.*  However ...

"I won't forgive me" sounds technically like two separate entities are intended to exist, one doing the forgiving and one receiving the forgiving.

So this could be used as a literary or lyrical device to express a person who feels split amongst themselves and not in control of their own actions.  In the context of forgiving oneself, one is certainly trying to bring something of themselves under control of themselves, but has failed.

Though it is far more likely *me* was chosen because it's one syllable and flows with the rhythm of the song better than *myself*.  Intentional rule-breaking like this is not uncommon in songs and poems.